# How to extract the Clock Time from Website Javascript js.clock()

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Is it possible to extract the time from the site: https://w2.leisurelink.lcsd.gov.hk/index/index.jsp

I am using selenium, and seems like the time is generated from a javascript, so extracting the text for the element wouldn't work.

[image]

Comment: `js_time= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//form[@name='theClock']")
val = driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value;", js_time)
print(val)` .. just run this, you may have to change the xpath as I am not certain which node you really want to locate.

Answer (score 0):

To extract the time you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50468629/python-selenium-wait-until-element-is-fully-loaded/50474905#50474905) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://w2.leisurelink.lcsd.gov.hk/index/index.jsp")
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='theTime']"))).get_attribute("value"))
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://w2.leisurelink.lcsd.gov.hk/index/index.jsp")
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='theTime']"))).get_attribute("value"))
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  12-12-2021 20:45:15
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```